# mySQL PDO not enabled in phpinfo()

Tags: mysql, apache, php

I am trying to setup a local PHP development envrironment but am having trouble getting mySQL enabled for PDO and am fairly new to this type of setup...so Im not sure what I could be missing.

I have uncommented:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and set the extension_dir to:

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext\"
```

Also, I have copied the libmysql.dll file to the Bin dir in Apache and I am sure I am checking the right php.ini file.

When I open phpinfo() I get the following:

```
**mysql**
Active Persistent Links  0  
Active Links  0  
Client API version  5.0.27  

Directive Local Value Master Value 
mysql.allow_persistent On On 
mysql.connect_timeout 60 60 
mysql.default_host no value no value 
mysql.default_password no value no value 
mysql.default_port no value no value 
mysql.default_socket no value no value 
mysql.default_user no value no value 
mysql.max_links Unlimited Unlimited 
mysql.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited 
mysql.trace_mode Off Off 


**mysqli**
Client API library version  5.0.27  
Client API header version  5.0.22  
MYSQLI_SOCKET  /tmp/mysql.sock  

Directive Local Value Master Value 
mysqli.default_host no value no value 
mysqli.default_port 3306 3306 
mysqli.default_pw no value no value 
mysqli.default_socket no value no value 
mysqli.default_user no value no value 
mysqli.max_links Unlimited Unlimited 
mysqli.reconnect Off Off 

**PDO**
PDO drivers  no value
```

Running `php.exe -m` on the command line gives me the following error:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_mysql.dll' - the specified module could not be found.
```

I get the above error for:

```
php_mysql.dll
php_pdo_mysql.dll
php_pdo.dll
```

If I enable sqlite, that shows up fine in the phpinfo() listing.

Whe I go to the page that is supposed to be using the mysql connection I get the following error:

**Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\connection.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\connection.php(11): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=xxx....', 'loginname', 'password') #1 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\pagename.php(18): include('C:\Inetpub\wwwr...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test\connection.php on line 11

Using EasyPHP for development. Didn't have a problem until I had to use mySQL

Comment: Well, if you really moved the library to the apache bin dir you answered your own question...

Comment: You've answered your own question you say you've put the .dll in /apache/bin when php is looking in /php/ext/

Comment: Moved or copied?... Do those php_*.dll exist in the ext folder as well?

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: There's normally no need to move `libmysql.dll` anywhere. And it's complaining about `php_mysql.dll` which is the legacy extension, not PDO.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I copied the libmysql.dll to the Apache Bin because the mySQL listing wasn't showing in phpinfo() until I did that...also its throwing errors for php_pdo.dll and php_pdo_mysql.dll as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried many suggestions but the one that worked was remove everything and start over.

Got rid of WAMP and loaded XAMPP now mySQL is up and running using PDO.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP from Apache und the command line are two different things:

You put libmysql into apaches bin-folder. When you start php from the command line, libmysql must be also accessible from there, eg. when it is in PATH.

Comment: Thanks tw...I do have the dir locations set in PATH...wondering why sqlite will enable under PDO but mysql will not.